# How do I access the TextField and set it to a String? I'm using scenebuilder and eclipse

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, textfield, scenebuilder

I'm writing a very simple UI for bank account management. I try to get whatever Name the user writes in a *textbox* and set it to a *string*. I'm also trying to print something to the user by using a `textArea` instead of `System.out.print();` but whenever I try `getText()` or `setText()` i get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "javafx.scene.control.TextField.getText()" because "this.txtName" is
> null at application.Controller.addPersonClick(Controller.java:26).

Some help would be much appreciated. I am using **eclipse** and **Scenebuilder**.

This is what my code looks like in the `class Controller` (not all of it):

```
PersonRegister register = new PersonRegister();
Person per = new Person();
Account account = new Account();

@FXML
public void addPersonClick(ActionEvent event) {
    String nameIn = txtName.getText(); //Error
    String pNbrIn = "temp"; //Works fine
    if(register.findPerson(pNbrIn) == null) {
        per.setName(nameIn);
        per.setPNbr(pNbrIn);
        register.addPerson(per);
        System.out.println("Added "+per.getName()+" "+per.getPNbr()); //Works fine
        txtAreaResponse.setText("Added "+per.getName()+" "+per.getPNbr());//Error
    } else {
        System.out.println("Person already exists");//Works fine
        txtAreaResponse.setText("Person already exists"); //Error
    }
}
```

Here is the code to my UI (regarding the relevant `textField` and `textArea`):

```
<TextField layoutX="16.0" layoutY="32.0" />
<TextArea layoutX="17.0" layoutY="263.0" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="402.0" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Give the TextField an ID in scene builder, i'm assuming `myTextField` in below code. Then in your controller class declare it as such.

```java
@FXML
private TextField myTextField;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation and but on the contrary I have assigned the Ids in the scene builder as well as in the controller of the page

Comment: answer or question .. ? If the former, please explain a bit more clearly what _excactly_ you did to solve the (ill-defined by the OP ;) problem :)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33843324)